# (Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS) Cannot install python3-pip, error message (code 1) appear

Tags: apt, package-management, python, dpkg, python3

I have a problem when trying to install python3-pip on Ubuntu 22.04.

I got the Ubuntu from [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and run on USB drive. Then as python3/pip is in the universe repository, I enabled the universe repository here:

[image: enable universe repository]

Then I followed the [webpage](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-22.04/) that teaches you how to install pip for python3 with these commands:

```
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

The problem happened to the line: `sudo apt install python3-pip`.

When I execute this line, the screen goes black showing the Ubuntu logo and back to the terminal and continue installation, but then it comes out an error message:

[image: Error message screen]

and few seconds later the whole Ubuntu system hangs and I need to hard reboot the computer. I tried to google and get instructions, but all were useless.

From my couple trial and error experience ([Error message screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpEv6.jpg)), I notice that the problem appears when the installation comes after the line: /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-SK60iU/48-python3-pip_22.0.2+dfsg-1ubuntu0.3_all.deb**

Then I get a black screen, and the terminal shows up again with message: `E: sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1), Unable to read /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-SK60iU opendir (2: No such file or directory)`

Could the error caused by the Ubuntu server?

Comment: Are you using a live USB? (haven't installed to disk)

Comment: Yes. I boot the OS on USB, not installed to disk. Actually I do the same procedures last month and everything is good. But this time I got this problem.

Comment: I don't think you are able to install new packages on a live USB. Even if you are, the live USB is read-only and everything is stored in memory. Do you have enough RAM? Your `pip3 --version` in the screenshot shows you have already installed `python3-pip`.

Comment: Yes. I have 16GB of memory. The screenshot showing pip3-version is not mine, it's the instruction from the webpage. Do you mean I have to install the OS on a hard disk? Can Ubuntu installed on a usb drive?

Comment: You can use the current live USB to install to another USB. I do not know how to replace a live USB with a regular install.

Comment: OK. let me try it first. Thanks.